# Is there a "bitbucket_document" output setting for Rmarkdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown, bitbucket

I built an internal R package that I host on the company's bitbuckets.  My Rmarkdown knits to
"github_document".

The image links are broken when I view the Readme on bitbucket.

When I visit the package's page, it tries to link to this file, and fails:

https://mybicketbucket.ca/users/myusername/repos/mypackage/man/figures/README-unnamed-chunk-7-1.png

left-clicking on readme.md, it links to this file and successfully displays the image:

https://mybicketbucket.ca/users/myusername/repos/mypackage/browse/man/figures/README-unnamed-chunk-7-1.png?raw=

any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add in your first chunk.

```
knitr::opts_knit$set(base.url = "raw/")
```

The md file will not be pretty on your package repo but it will print the figure on bitbucket.

Comment: thanks - you are a gentleman and a scholar.  :)

I haven't tested your solution.  I ended up naming the chunks and that fixed the links .  For example, the pressure/plot ggplot graph in  usethis::use_readme_rmd() is displayed fine without doing anything.